# zend framework : how to put parameter

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have 2 function in controller zend php

```
public  function jurnalAction()
    {
        $tahun                          = ($_REQUEST['tahun']=='')?date('Y'):$_REQUEST['tahun'];
        $this->view->tahunSearch        = $tahun;
        $this->view->tahunSelect        = Komponent::tahunSelect($tahun,'tahun'); 
        $this->view->list               = $this->getModel()->getDocumentNoJO($tahun);  
            $tanggal                        = $_POST['tanggal'];
        $lokasi                         = $_POST['LOCATION_CD'];
        $this->view->dataBank           = $this->getModel()->getBankPenerimaBunga();
        $data                           = $this->getModel()->getdataJurnal($docno,$sort,$lokasi,$tanggal);          
        $this->view->master             = $data['master'];
        $this->view->detail             = $data['detail'];
        $this->view->total              = $data['total'];
        //$bilangan                         = $this->getConvertUang();
        $komponent                      = new Komponent();
        $this->view->dibuatSelect       = $komponent->pejabatSelect2('','dibuat');
        $this->view->pengawasSelect     = $komponent->pejabatSelect2('','pengawas');
        $this->view->manKeuSelect       = $komponent->pejabatSelect2('','manKeu');
        $this->view->pkasSelect         = $komponent->pejabatSelect2('','pkas');

    }
    public function jurnalbalikAction()
    {
        $docno                          = str_replace('|','/',$this->_request->getParam('docno'));
        $tanggal                        = $data['master']['TRAN_DT'] ;
        $lokasi                         = $_POST['LOCATION_CD'];
        $data                           = $this->getModel()->getdataJurnal($docno,$sort,$lokasi,$tanggal);  
        $data['master']['APPROVAL_CD']  = 'B';
        $data['master']['CR_AMT_RP']    = 0;
        $data['master']['DR_AMT_RP']    = 0;
        $data['master']['JENIS_KARTU']  = '14';
        $data['master']['USER_ID']      = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity()->USER_ID;
        $data['master']['UPD_DT']       = new Zend_Db_Expr('SYSDATE');
        $data['master']['REMARKS']      = 'Jurnal Koreksi Kembail '.str_replace('Jurnal','',$data['master']['REMARKS']);        
        unset($data['master']['LOKASI']);
        unset($data['master']['JK']);
        unset($data['master']['V_MY']);
        unset($data['master']['VTRAN_DT']);
        $this->getModel()->insertJurnalBalik($data);
        $this->_redirect('pph/jurnal');
    }
```

on function jurnalbalik i want to put parameter tanggal from function jurnal

Answer (score 0):

I think it's impossible. they are two differrent actions. You can call one action at a time only.

However, try researching `forward()` method, hope that help you.

Document: [Action Controllers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.action.html)

Comment: thank, i was try use forward() , but if use that, the action will put all action in jurnalAction,